# Rails & Devise: User accounts not deleting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using the Devise gem for the first time to authenticate users. I can sign up, log out, sign in, and edit user accounts without issues, but deleting accounts isn't working! When I click the button to delete, the JS confirmation pops up asking if I want to delete, I click yes... and then I'm redirected to the user's show page. User account is intact.

In `views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb`:

```
<p>Unhappy? <%= button_to "Cancel my account", '/users/#{@user.id}',   data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, method: :destroy, class: "btn btn-danger" %></p>
```

In my UsersController:

```
  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy

    if @user.destroy
        redirect_to root_path
    end
 end
```

I'm still shaky on Rails routing, but in my routes.rb I have:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
```

as well as:

```
resources :users
```

And when I run rake routes, the two routes I think may be associated are:

```
DELETE /users(.:format)          registrations#destroy
DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      users#destroy
```

I'm pretty sure that I'm doing something wrong with the routes, but I can't see what. Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users, only: :destroy

#view
<%= button_to "Cancel my account", @user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
```

---

**Resources**

The problem you have is you're not calling the [`delete` HTTP verb](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp); instead, you're calling it as `destroy` (`method: :destroy`).

To give context, the HTTP protocol is populated with a series of [*verbs*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods), to help you define different "actions" for a particular resource (url). Here's Wikipedia's explanation:

> `HTTP` defines methods (sometimes referred to as *verbs*) to indicate the desired action to be performed on the identified resource. What this resource represents, whether pre-existing data or data that is generated dynamically, depends on the implementation of the server.

Thus when you use the `resources` helper in the [*routes* of your app](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web), you'll see which *routes* are generated:

[image]

As can be seen above, each time you declare routes for a particular `resource`, Rails auto populates with several predefined urls / paths. In order for your app to process your requests properly, you have to send it to the requested URL - and it has to be valid.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Got my verbs and actions mixed up!

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<p>Unhappy? <%= button_to "Cancel my account", '/users/#{@user.id}',   data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, method: :destroy, class: "btn btn-danger" %></p>
```

to

```
<p>Unhappy? <%= button_to "Cancel my account", '/users/#{@user.id}',   data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger" %></p>
```

You should use `method: :delete` not `method: :destroy`

Comment: Thanks! I had my verbs and actions mixed up!